# Amortized analysis of resizing array implementation of a stack

Tags: algorithms, amortized-analysis

Here is an excerpt from the book Algorithms, 4th edition by R. Sedgewick and K. Wayne:

> Proposition E. In the resizing array implementation of Stack
>   (Algorithm 1.1), the average number of array accesses for any sequence
>   of operations starting from an empty data structure is constant in the
>   worst case.
>
> Proof sketch: For each push() that causes the array to grow ( say from
>   size N to size 2N), consider the N/2 - 1 push() operations that most
>   recently caused the stack size to grow to k, for k from N/2 + 2 to N.
>   Averaging the 4N array accesses to grow the array with N/2 array
>   accesses (one for each push), we get an average cost of 9 array
>   accesses per operation.

It is unclear to me why **4N** array accesses are required to grow the array. From my understanding, in the proof they describe the case when the array grows from size N to 2N, and for that it should require only 2N array accesses (copy the first N elements, 2 array accesses per element).

Comment: I wouldn't fuss about constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They include the initialization of the new array.

From page 207 of the text:

> Q. Does `int[] a = new int[N]` count as *N* array accesses (to initialize entries to 0)?
>
> A. Most likely yes, so we make that assumption in this book, though a sophisticated compiler implementation might try to avoid this cost for huge sparse arrays.

Comment: Why is initialization necessary? Also, even considering initialization, we only get 3N operations.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It's not in this case but the book focuses on Java which in most implementations will initialize new arrays in linear time. If we resize a size N stack then we have initialization of 2N array, N reads, and N writes for total of 4N.